# Difference between tables on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Just a quick one, i've got a great tutorial that explains exactly what I need to do for part of my project, but it's written for iPhone, are there any major differences/pitfalls I should look out for?

thanks

Comment: "Difference between tables on iPhone and iPad" there is no difference.(tables).(may be some methods are not available that is in other, but generally used methods are available, you can check method definition for which iOS you are using).

Answer (score 0):

While the code used for the iPhone can be run on an iPad without any changes, there are some design principles you should take into mind.  Merely making a huge tableView that fills the screen isn't the way it's done on an iPad.  Usually tables are put in a Popover view, that is much better suited to displaying data on the iPad.